# Multi select files in media browser

Tags: media

I would like to multi-select files in media browser. I came across this sandbox module: [Media Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676) but it has bugs that render it not usable. Does anyone know of a solution to multi-selecting files in media browser?

Comment: And just as i post this I find the patch media_multiselect-update_for_new_media-2216273-32.patch to work, though it does not apply smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are using this patch on latest media to multi-select media files on fields: https://www.drupal.org/node/951004#comment-9681531

Personally I had some problems to make it work at first, but finally I got it working (Had to disable admin_language module).